# AWS Lambda EndPoint can change?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Can we change API ID Or Endpoint from API gateway ? because I need my older URL,which most of users use that url for posting there data , but it has been changed accidentally,is there any way to redirect request ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes! There is a service within API Gateway called [Custom domain names](https://console.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/main/publish/domain-names) where you can achieve what exactly what you're requesting.

I will provide you [this resource from AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/custom-domain-name-amazon-api-gateway/) that discusses how to set custom domain names for different API Gateway API types (REST, WebSocket, HTTP), as they each have slightly different instructions to follow.

Another option to consider is registering an internet domain using Amazon Route 53 or another a third-party domain registrar.